# Dynamic created content iframe issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I have written a javascript function to create simple content iframe, its work fine in all browser IE9,8,7 and chrome but not working in mozilla firefox, what is issue with my code? even not getting any exception in console.

```
function (parent, child, cssfile, jsfilepath) {

        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = ('MyID' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000000000000) + 1));
        iframe.frameBorder = '0';
        iframe.scrolling = 'no';
        iframe.marginWidth = '0';
        iframe.marginHeight = '0';
        iframe.hspace = '0';
        iframe.vspace = '0';
        iframe.allowTransparency = "true";

        parent.appendChild(iframe);

        var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        var inter = window.setInterval(function() {
             if(iframeDoc.readyState == "complete") {
                 window.clearInterval(inter);

                 iframeDoc.body.innerHTML = child;

                 iframeDoc.body.style.background = "transparent";

                 addExternalCss(cssfile, iframeDoc);
                 addEmbedCss('body {margin:0px; padding:0px;}', iframeDoc);
                 addJs(jsfilepath, iframeDoc);
             }
         },100);
    }
```

**Edit**

Just displaying blank iframe in firebug

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="MyId350236077714409500" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<html><head></head><body></body></html>

</iframe>
```

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins to see whether one of them is blocking the content?

Comment: which kind of plugin? firefox addons?

Comment: Yes, try to disable all your addons for a moment and check if the page works properly without them. If so turn them on one by one to find out which one is causing problems.

Comment: sorry i forgot to update i found my answer no need to disable any plugin

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer

```
function (parent, child, cssfile, jsfilepath) {

        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = ('MyID' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000000000000) + 1));
        iframe.frameBorder = '0';
        iframe.scrolling = 'no';
        iframe.marginWidth = '0';
        iframe.marginHeight = '0';
        iframe.hspace = '0';
        iframe.vspace = '0';
        iframe.allowTransparency = "true";

        parent.appendChild(iframe);



        var inter = window.setInterval(function() {
             // put inside function 
             var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

             if(iframeDoc.readyState == "complete") {
                 window.clearInterval(inter);

                 iframeDoc.body.innerHTML = child;

                 iframeDoc.body.style.background = "transparent";

                 addExternalCss(cssfile, iframeDoc);
                 addEmbedCss('body {margin:0px; padding:0px;}', iframeDoc);
                 addJs(jsfilepath, iframeDoc);
             }
         },100);
    }
```